# Что изображено, корпус или абажур?

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли назвать каркас, обрамляющий лампу, корпусом или абажуром?

Comment: Можно. Так его и назовут.

Comment: @tum_ Так как так-то?

Comment: :) [Абажур](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&biw=1880&bih=938&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=O5lBXfiaDI2bgQbonLKQCg&q=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&oq=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&gs_l=img.12...0.0..27847...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz-img.yAKoTfde2iU&ved=0ahUKEwi4pP6io9_jAhWNTcAKHWiODKIQ4dUDCAY), подвесной.

Comment: Но ведь абажур заслоняет лицо от засветки, чего не делает эта конструкция...

Comment: @Владимир Такое в языке случается. Когда кто-то "бросает трубку", он ведь не бросает мобильник на асфальт, да и трубки там никакой нет.